# Canon EF-S 10-18mm f/4.5-5.6 IS STM for night landscapes and possible astrophotography

Tags: canon, astrophotography, cropped-sensor, ultra-wide, night-photography

Does anyone have any experience with the Canon 10-18 used specifically for night landscapes or for doubling in Astro photography? I already understand it is a slow lens, and obviously not the first choice for these scenarios, I got it for photographing historical sites overseas (in the day) and thought to try some other scenarios with it. Some examples of what I am thinking are, with upcoming travels in the Middle East I want to document old mosques, desert fortresses, and mountain scenes, at night.

Comment: You might think about editing your question a bit and add what you are trying to achive or avoid. Or are you asking for techniques to use with that equipment?

Answer (score 1):

I have it and I have tried it for night landscapes. The big problem that you will face, apart from it being slow, is that it is a focus-by-wire lens and focusing accurately to infinity, with very low light is very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

All things considered, this is an incredible little lens for landscape and fascinating angles, take a stab at shooting low and near an object with the landscape out of sight and you'll be compensated with a charming shot, anyway abstain from utilizing it for single pictures as your subject may not be enthused about the wide edge impact! It's extraordinary for wide gatherings shots, however, one for the pack that may wind up on your camera more than you might suspect!

Comment: While you obliquely mention this lens's suitability to landscapes in the first 2 clauses of the first sentence, your answer doesn't talk at all about this lens's suitability for _night_ landscapes or astrophotography, which is what the question was asking. Do you have any experience with this lens with night landscapes or astrophotography?